# Minkowski sum of two polytopes via the halfspace representation

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polyhedra

If i have two polytopes denoted by $P_1, P_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, suppose their halfspace representations are respectively $H_1x \leq K_1$ and $H_2x \leq K_2$. Now, considering their Minkowski sum, namely $H_1 \oplus H_2$, i ask myself whether their exists an explicit relation between the halfspace representation of $H_1 \oplus H_2$ and the ones of $H_1, H_2$.

Thanks in advance,

Bests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me try to answer this question. According to

*H.R. Tiwary, "On the hardness of computing intersection, union and Minkowski sum of polytopes". Discrete & Computational Geometry, p. 469–479, 2008*

the problem of enumerating all rows of the matrix representing $H_1\oplus H_2$ is NP-hard. So: No, there is no explicit relation between the $\mathcal{H}$-representation of $H_1\oplus H_2$ and $H_1$ and $H_2$.

However, for computational purposes there are some tricks to cope with this restriction, for example, you could use *support functions* or *symbolic orthogonal projections*. The latter gives you an explicit $\mathcal{H}$-representation of a higher dimensional polyhedron whose orthogonal projection is the Minkowski sum $H_1\oplus H_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your really useful answer.